# What's the format string for `git reflog` default output?

Tags: git

I want to tweak the default output of `git reflog`, but I first need the format string to reproduce the default output.  Specifically, I'm having trouble with the coloring of the different refnames:

[image: git-reflog]

Can someone more knowledgable with Git help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Per [the `git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html):

> `git reflog show` is an alias for `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline`

which should then send you to [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), which says little about `--pretty=oneline`, but hides an important bit under the `-g` aka `--walk-reflogs` description:

> With `--pretty` format other than `oneline` (for obvious reasons), this causes the output to have two extra lines of information taken from the reflog. The reflog designator in the output may be shown as `ref@{Nth}` (where `Nth` is the reverse-chronological index in the reflog) or as `ref@{timestamp}` (with the timestamp for that entry), depending on a few rules:
>
> 1. If the starting point is specified as `ref@{Nth}`, show the index format.
> 2. If the starting point was specified as `ref@{now}`, show the timestamp format.
> 3. If neither was used, but `--date` was given on the command line, show the timestamp in the format requested by `--date`.
> 4. Otherwise, show the index format.
>
> Under `--pretty=oneline`, the commit message is prefixed with this information on the same line. This option cannot be combined with `--reverse`. See also [git-reflog(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).

The "starting point" this alludes to is *which* reflog entry you gave with your `git log -g` command.  If you did not give one, `git log` defaults to `HEAD`, which doesn't have either format, so this falls into rule 3 or 4:

```
git log --pretty=oneline -g HEAD@{now}
```

explicitly uses rule 2, but:

```
git log --pretty=oneline -g HEAD@{0}
```

explicitly uses rule 1, for instance.

The little it says, or doesn't say, about `--pretty=oneline` is that it is roughly equivalent to `%H %gd %s` or `%h %gd %s` depending on whether you use `--abbrev-commit`.  But—this also is somewhat missing from the documentation—if you set `log.decorate=auto` in your configuration *and* stdout is going to an interactive device,<sup>1</sup> you also get `%d` inserted.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Interactive device" is whatever is designated a "tty" by the C library `isatty` function.

Comment: According to his image, the %d is inserted. I could replicate the style in the question example by using: `git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h%d %gd: %gs'`.

A useful style that I built upon it was: `git reflog --format='%C(yellow)%h %C(magenta)%gd: %C(auto)%gs %d[%C(240)%as%C(auto)]' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m'`

Answer (score 3):

The default format string for `reflog` is something like this:

```
git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %gd: %gs (%s)'
```

Colors can be modified with `%C`.  For example, to change the initial yellow to magenta:

```
git reflog --format='%C(magenta)%h%C(reset) %gd: %gs (%s)'
```

Note that `%C(reset)` is absolutely necessary because coloring is achieved using `ANSI escape sequences` and they must be correctly terminated. If you're curios look into `color.h` in `git` code to see how these sequences look like.

For all possible format strings see `format:<string>` in `man git-log`:

> ```
>    ·   format:<string>
>
>        The format:<string> format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little
>        bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with %n instead of \n.
>
>        E.g, format:"The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n" would show something like this:
>
>            The author of fe6e0ee was Junio C Hamano, 23 hours ago
>            The title was >>t4119: test autocomputing -p<n> for traditional diff input.<<
>
>        The placeholders are:
>
>        ·   %H: commit hash
>
>        ·   %h: abbreviated commit hash
>
>        ·   %T: tree hash
>
>        ·   %t: abbreviated tree hash
>
>        ·   %P: parent hashes
>
>        ·   %p: abbreviated parent hashes
>
>        ·   %an: author name
>
>        ·   %aN: author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %ae: author email
>
>        ·   %aE: author email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %ad: author date (format respects --date= option)
>
>        ·   %aD: author date, RFC2822 style
>
>        ·   %ar: author date, relative
>
>        ·   %at: author date, UNIX timestamp
>
>        ·   %ai: author date, ISO 8601-like format
>
>        ·   %aI: author date, strict ISO 8601 format
>
>        ·   %cn: committer name
>
>        ·   %cN: committer name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %ce: committer email
>
>        ·   %cE: committer email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %cd: committer date (format respects --date= option)
>
>        ·   %cD: committer date, RFC2822 style
>
>        ·   %cr: committer date, relative
>
>        ·   %ct: committer date, UNIX timestamp
>
>        ·   %ci: committer date, ISO 8601-like format
>
>        ·   %cI: committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
>
>        ·   %d: ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log(1)
>
>        ·   %D: ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.
>
>        ·   %e: encoding
>
>        ·   %s: subject
>
>        ·   %f: sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
>
>        ·   %b: body
>
>        ·   %B: raw body (unwrapped subject and body)
>
>        ·   %N: commit notes
>
>        ·   %GG: raw verification message from GPG for a signed commit
>
>        ·   %G?: show "G" for a good (valid) signature, "B" for a bad signature, "U" for a good signature with
>            unknown validity and "N" for no signature
>
>        ·   %GS: show the name of the signer for a signed commit
>
>        ·   %GK: show the key used to sign a signed commit
>
>        ·   %gD: reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}
>
>        ·   %gd: shortened reflog selector, e.g., stash@{1}
>
>        ·   %gn: reflog identity name
>
>        ·   %gN: reflog identity name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %ge: reflog identity email
>
>        ·   %gE: reflog identity email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>
>        ·   %gs: reflog subject
>
>        ·   %Cred: switch color to red
>
>        ·   %Cgreen: switch color to green
>
>        ·   %Cblue: switch color to blue
>
>        ·   %Creset: reset color
>
>        ·   %C(...): color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the
>            beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or
>            --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal).  auto
>            alone (i.e.  %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is
>            switched again.
>
>        ·   %m: left, right or boundary mark
>
>        ·   %n: newline
>
>        ·   %%: a raw %
>
>        ·   %x00: print a byte from a hex code
>
>        ·   %w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]]): switch line wrapping, like the -w option of git-shortlog(1).
>
>        ·   %<(<N>[,trunc|ltrunc|mtrunc]): make the next placeholder take at least N columns, padding spaces
>            on the right if necessary. Optionally truncate at the beginning (ltrunc), the middle (mtrunc) or
>            the end (trunc) if the output is longer than N columns. Note that truncating only works correctly
>            with N >= 2.
>
>        ·   %<|(<N>): make the next placeholder take at least until Nth columns, padding spaces on the right
>            if necessary
>
>        ·   %>(<N>), %>|(<N>): similar to %<(<N>), %<|(<N>) respectively, but padding spaces on the left
>
>        ·   %>>(<N>), %>>|(<N>): similar to %>(<N>), %>|(<N>) respectively, except that if the next
>            placeholder takes more spaces than given and there are spaces on its left, use those spaces
>
>        ·   %><(<N>), %><|(<N>): similar to % <(<N>), %<|(<N>) respectively, but padding both sides (i.e. the
>            text is centered)
> ```

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot to mention the %C color parts.  It's worth mentioning, though, that as with other named `--pretty=` formats, `--pretty=oneline` cannot be captured by a single fixed set of `%`-directives as the formatting is done by ad hoc code that may not always have an equivalent %-directive. What this means for the OP depends on precisely what he wants as output.

Comment: fwiw, for me it's `'%C(auto)%h %gd: %gs'`. The trailing ` (%s)` is superfluous; `%gs` includes it already, apparently. I verified this via `diff -q <(git reflog) <(git reflog --format='%C(auto)%h %gd: %gs') && echo same || echo different`